# Downloading File Code changes file content and affects ability to decrypt file

Tags: python, encryption, urllib

When I download a file from my server using Python and urlib2, the files contents are slightly different than what they should be.

They are different in that there are extra lines("\r\n" or "\n") added to the downloaded version of the file. This isn't a major problem for a file that is in xml form but its a major problem when my file is encrypted because the file contents are slightly different and they cant be decrypted.

I know its my download code thats altering the file contents and not the file thats on the server being wrong because I have downloaded that file using FTP and found it has the correct content when I download it that way. Some more useful information: the file is ASCII encoded. My server is Windows .NET and I'm unsure if the http response is ascii or unicode - maybe that could be causing the problem?

How can I make urlib2 download my file from my server and ensure that the content doesn't change?

Original content:

```
     <clientlist>


       <client>
         <clientauthblah>blah</clientauthblah>
         <version9>blah</version9>
         <version10>blah</version10>
         <companyno>1</companyno>
         <companyname>blah</companyname>
       </client>
```

When I run my download code this is the content I get, this is something I cant have because my files are encrypted and it means I cant decrypt the file:

```
 <clientlist>




   <client>

     <clientauthblah>blah</clientauthblah>

     <version9>blah</version9>

     <version10>blah</version10>

     <companyno>1</companyno>

     <companyname>blah</companyname>

   </client>
```

Heres my code:

```
# Download
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mywebsite.com/Clients.xml")
output    = open("tempEncrypted.xml",'w')
res       = response.read()
output.write(res)
output.close()
```

Comment: Try downloading it in using FTP in binary mode. That will prevent the line ending translation

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x by any chance?

Comment: @frb no I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Please print the headers (from `response.info()`). My guess is that you've got a misconfigured server that's treating "tempEncrypted.xml" as `text/xml` or `application/xml` or something similar, and sending that as the `Content-Type`. Since that content type explicitly means "this is text where the whitespace is unimportant", it's perfectly valid for either side to do anything it wants to the newlines. If this is the problem, there are ways you can work around it, but the right solution is to stop using a content type that doesn't match your content.

Comment: Also, you should be using mode `'wb'`, not `'w'`, in the `open` command. Opening files in text mode can _also_ do newline conversions (especially on Windows).

Comment: @abarnert thanks very much. By writting the file as binary 'wb' it worked correctly :) You should make an answer so I can accept :)

Comment: Your added question: "I'm unsure if the http response is ascii or unicode - maybe that could be causing the problem?" If the HTTP response is supposed to be a binary encrypted file, it's neither ASCII nor Unicode, it's binary data, so this shouldn't come up. (Of course once you decrypt it, if you get UTF-16-LE where you expected ASCII or UTF-8, that'll be a second problem… but let's get past this one first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this line:

```
output    = open("tempEncrypted.xml",'w')
```

Python opens files in text mode by default, which means you may get newline conversions. The details are complicated by platform differences, universal newlines, etc.

But if you have binary data, the answer is simple: open it in binary mode, by using `'wb'` instead of `'w'`:

```
output    = open("tempEncrypted.xml",'wb')
```